# Lan not working if cable not inside while booting

Tags: boot, lan

I have an annoying problem. Every time the LAN cable is not in while booting, I cannot get any connection to the internet, network, router, etc.
I tried to plug in and out the cable several times - but nothing happened, besides that I always shows that LAN is disconnected.
The same happens after sleeping mode.

I am new to Ubuntu (12.04) and hoping for a hint!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

DHCP protocol can not assign your NIC an IP address without a cable connected.
Obtain root acces in a console and execute `dhclient eth0` where eth0 is the name of your NIC.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a terminal and use this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

if this does not work, try stopping and starting the connection:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start
```

Comment: sorry.. that did not solve my problem..
i could furthermore not restart the networking after stopping.